# How to give App id to a facebook share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Am using share button on my website and the code is

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>" title="Facebook share" ><img style="margin-right: 10px;" src="_images/facebook_share.png" alt="facebook share button"/></a>
```

and the `$pageUrl` is the current page url fetched from address bar using PHP

what i need i have to add app id for this share and that should display in my app insite
How to do this...

Comment: Well, what's the url of your app?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the sharer.php endpoint is old and doesn't support much of the current functionality of the API - look at the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead